# How to resotore outlined form Html canvas using GDI+

Tags: c#, html, canvas, gdi+

we have a web patiner project use browser (js) draw something, like image, text etc. and restore by GDI+ to export a image to print. every think looks like well, except outlined text:

In web application we use HTML5 CanvasRenderingContext2D 'fillText' and 'strokeText'.

In winform we use GDI+ like this:

```
                g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
                g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;

             using (var newFont = new Font(family, emSize, this.FontStyle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel))
                    {
                        using (GraphicsPath path =
                       GetStringPath(this.Text, g.DpiY, new PointF(0, 0),
                       newFont,
                       StringFormat.GenericTypographic))
                        {
                            var bounds = path.GetBounds();



                            if (this.OutlineWidth > 0)
                            {
                                //scale stroke。
                                float strokeWidth = this.OutlineWidth * (emSize / this.FontSize);
                                using (Pen p = new Pen(this.OutlineColor, strokeWidth))
                                {
                                    g.DrawPath(p, path);
                                }
                            }

                            if (this.FontColor != Color.Transparent)
                            {
                                using (Brush b = new SolidBrush(this.FontColor))
                                {
                                    g.FillPath(b, path);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
```

but result have some diffrent:

[this is generated by canvas to toDataUrl](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rUoNa.jpg)

[this is generated by GDI+](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSohl.jpg)

how to smooth gdi path? please help! sorry for my bad English! thanks.

Comment: Please post javascript code also.

Comment: For smoothing the the Graphics.SmoothingMode! What exactly do you want to change in the GDI result? The difference I see is mostly the smaller (and nicer) stroke width..

Comment: @TaW it was used: g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                    g.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.ClearTypeGridFit;
                    g.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;

Comment: @stjepano fabricjs with modified was used in javascript for drawing